# Inserting rows with multiple NSFetchedResultsController's

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am downloading information from the internet and using the data to create entities in Core Data. I am trying to sort the entities (The entities are TV Shows, the data is from Trakt) by the `airDate` attribute of a `TVEpisode` entity that has a relationship to the `TVShow` entity. The `TVShow` entity only has this relationship to the show if the show data has an episode that is airing at a future date from the current time.

So the way I want to sort the data is:
Top: Shows that have a upcomingEpisode relationship, sorted by the `airDate` attribute of the `upcomingEpisode`, ordered ascendingly.
Middle: Shows that have no `upcomingEpisode` relationship but will be returning.
Bottom: Shows that have no `upcomingEpisode` relationship and that are ended/cancelled

Here are the issues I am running into getting this to work.

Issue 1: Using 1 `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
    let airDateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "upcomingEpisode.airDate", ascending: true)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [airDateSort, titleSort];

    upcomingShowsResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "upcomingShows")
    upcomingShowsResultsController.delegate = self;

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if (!upcomingShowsResultsController.performFetch(&error)) {
        println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Using this `NSFetchedResultsController` will put all `TVShow` entities with no `upcomingEpisode` relationship on top, sorted all by title, I need the dead shows sorted by title on the very bottom and returning shows sorted by title in the middle.

Issue 2: Using multiple `NSFetchedResultsController`'s

```
func setupUpcomingShowsFetchedResultsController() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
    let airDateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "upcomingEpisode.airDate", ascending: true)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [airDateSort, titleSort];

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "upcomingEpisode != nil")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    upcomingShowsResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "upcomingShows")
    upcomingShowsResultsController.delegate = self;

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if (!upcomingShowsResultsController.performFetch(&error)) {
        println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func setupReturningShowsFetchedResultsController() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort];

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "status == 'returning series'")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "upcomingEpisode == nil")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([predicate!, predicate2!])

    returningShowsResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    returningShowsResultsController.delegate = self;

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if (!returningShowsResultsController.performFetch(&error)) {
        println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func setupDeadShowsFetchedResultsController() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]

    let endedShowsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "status == 'ended'")
    fetchRequest.predicate = endedShowsPredicate

    deadShowsResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    deadShowsResultsController.delegate = self;

    var deadShowsError: NSError? = nil
    if (!deadShowsResultsController.performFetch(&deadShowsError)) {
        println("Error: \(deadShowsError?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

These work for what I want, but only when the data is already downloaded and in Core Data. When the app first launches and downloads the data it crashes every time because the number of rows in a section are not the same as what the table is expecting. I did manipulate the index paths that the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` gives in the `didChangeObject` function, and I printed out index's that are being inserted. The count that I did in any section was equal to how many the table view says it was expecting but it throws an error every time. This is how I am handling the method for multiple `NSFetchedResultsController's`

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        let section = sectionOfFetchedResultsController(controller)
        let indexPathsComputed = [NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath?.row ?? 0, inSection: section)]
        let newIndexPathsComputed = [NSIndexPath(forRow: newIndexPath?.row ?? 0, inSection: section)]

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            switch type {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(newIndexPathsComputed, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsComputed, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsComputed, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(newIndexPathsComputed, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
                if let index = indexPathsComputed[0] {
                    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as? ShowTableViewCell {
                        self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: index)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("No cell at index path")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

If the crashes could be fixed, this would be the best way to achieve what I want to do.

Issue 3: Using multiple Array's

```
func reloadShowsArray() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
    let airDateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "upcomingEpisode.airDate", ascending: true)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [airDateSort, titleSort];

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "upcomingEpisode != nil")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    var error: NSError?
    showsArray = coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [TVShow]
    if let error = error {
        println(error)
    }
}

func reloadDeadShows() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TVShow")
        let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]

        let endedShowsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "status == 'ended'")
        fetchRequest.predicate = endedShowsPredicate

        var error: NSError?
        deadShows = coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [TVShow]
        if let error = error {
            println(error)
        }
    }
```

This solves the crashing and works after the data is downloaded and while the data is being downloaded. But when using this, I have to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` when the data is downloaded, and the entities just pop into the table view with no animation, and I really want the animations from `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` because it looks better and is a better experience. I tried calling `reloadShowsArray()` and then using the `find()` function with the entity to get the index so I could use insertRowsAtIndexPaths, but it returns nil every time for the index, even though the entity was saved with the context before that. Also the cells will not get automatically reloaded or moved around like with `NSFetchedResultsController`

So what is the best way to handle this, and how can I get the desired sorting with the animations?

Comment: For option 1, what is the `status` of shows in the top section?  Could you sort by `status` first, in order to get top/middle/bottom in the correct order?  For option 2, do you have tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() in the other FRC delegate methods?  If not, that might explain the errors.  And even so, you might need to implement a counter, which is increased with each `controller:willChangeContent` call and decreased with each `controller:didChangeContent` call.  beginUpdates should only be called if the counter is at zero, and endUpdates only when it returns to zero.

Comment: Also in option 2, the errors might be linked to the dispatch_async, since it might result in the table updates happening outside the beginUpdates/endUpdates cycle.

Comment: The status is "returning series" for the top shows, "in production" for the middle shows and "ended"/"cancelled" for the bottom shows. I don't know why but sorting by that wasn't working the way I wanted before. I can try again, but it had a strange sorting. I will try the counter as well, that may work.. I use the dispatch_async in there because  I thought it would be easier than saving the context in every place on the main thread, because in the network requests they're not on the main thread so it just makes sure they are inserted correctly.

Comment: Doing the status sorting doesn't seem to work correctly. I have only the status sort, and the entities are in a strange order. The first one is "coming soon" then its "returning series" and then it goes back and forth. and then becomes all "returning series". So that's not working well.

Comment: Yes I have beginUpdates() and endUpdates() in those methods @pbasdf

Comment: The counter is working! It downloaded the data and displayed them correctly, it crashes because of `<__NSCFSet: 0x174262240> was mutated while being enumerated.` now after most of them are downloaded though. I also removed the dispatch_async from the methods and moved it around where I save the context. @pbasdf

Comment: Well that's some progress, but I'm afraid I have no idea about the "mutated whilst being enumerated" error.

Comment: Me nether, its breakpointing on `let episode = coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)`, and Im not mutating any sets I can see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73613/discussion-between-maximilian-and-pbasdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments, I suspect the three-FRC method causes problems because one FRC calls `controller:didChangeContent` (which triggers tableView.endUpdates) while another FRC is still processing updates.  To overcome this, implement a counter which is incremented in `controller:willChangeContent` and decremented in `controller:didChangeContent`.  The tableView `beginUpdates` should only be called if the counter is zero, and `endUpdates` only when the counter returns to zero.  That way, the endUpdates will only be called when all three FRCs have completed processing their updates.

If possible, I would also avoid the `dispatch_async`, since it could result in the table updates occurring outside the beginUpdates/endUpdates cycle.